# HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse reaction on server-side exceptions

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebresponse

I have identical, asynchronous `HTTP POST` code in a WP7 app and in a Windows Forms test app. When my service returns normal results everything is fine, and both apps get the same result.

But when I (on purpose) throw an exception in my service, the results are different. My Windows Forms app is giving me exactly what I've thrown (i.e. 'Unauthorized' or 'Bad Request' or whatever), while WP7 app always gives me the same 'Not Found' error.

Has anybody ever encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the `StatusCode`, you can use the statement below to get it:

```
  private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
  {
      try
      {
          ...
      }

      catch (WebException e)
      {
          HttpStatusCode code = ((HttpWebResponse) (e).Response).StatusCode;
      }
  }
```

Comment: YES! That will do. Thank you! I don't understand though why EndGetResponse gives me null when I try to get HttpWebResponse, and yet, as you point out, one can get that response object from the exception.